# Java: Generic Return Type, difference between using class parameter vs bracketed call?

Tags: java, generics, return-type

I need to interact with a complex legacy class that has nearly all its method arguments and return types as `Object`.

In my code, I know I will only be dealing with a small slice of functionality, and I know the exact types of all arguments and return types that will be used. In order to make my code more friendly, I'd like to bury any casting that may need to take place and work only with concrete types. I noticed there were two functionally identical ways I could wrap the legacy class method:

```
public class LegacyClass {
    public Object legacyMethod(Object o) {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
LegacyClass foo = new LegacyClass();

private <T> T legacyMethodWrapper1(String s) {
    return (T) foo.legacyMethod(s); //Warning: unchecked cast
}

private <T> T legacyMethodWrapper2(String s, Class<T> c) {
    return (T) foo.legacyMethod(s); //Warning: unchecked cast
}

public String getLegacyDataString1(String s) {
    return this.<String>legacyMethodWrapper1(s);
}

public String getLegacyDataString2(String s) {
    return this.legacyMethodWrapper2(s, String.class);
}
```

While there doesn't seem to be any functional difference in the simple code shown here, I was curious if I was missing some other subtle difference between `legacyMethodWrapper1` and `legacyMethodWrapper2`, other than the fact that `legacyMethodWrapper2` has access to the additional `Class` object, and could potentially do some more complex operations other than just casting?

Edit: To be clear, one of the goals of wrapping these legacy methods is 1) provide type safety to the *caller* and 2) prevent the caller from seeing meaningless warnings. Because I know more about the poorly designed legacy class than the compiler can ever know, I can provide a 100% type safe interface and hide any meaningless compiler warnings.

Comment: If the Java compiler throws an unchecked cast warning, then your code can be not type safe.  In particular, wrappers 1 and 2 really don't do anything that is significantly different than using a raw type.

Comment: Of course, the compiler can't really know the code *is* type safe, which is why I want to wrap and hide the casting and compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create separate method for each type unless you necessarily want it.

Below is my take -

```
class LegacyWrapper{
private Legacy legacy = new Legacy();
  public <T> T legacyMethodWrapper(Object obj ,Class<T> clazz) throws  ClassCastException{
    return clazz.cast(legacy.legacyMethod(obj));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is how I would do it, but I would probably create convenience methods for the main types (String, Integer, etc) that wrapped this method, like `public String getString(Object obj) {return legacyMethodWrapper(obj, String.class);}`

Comment: My goal was to prevent compiler warnings for the caller by providing methods with concrete types, which would hide the casting, so I would not want to expose the generic version as public, or throw exceptions...

Comment: The compiler warnings are doing their job: they're letting you know that your code may not be type safe.  Suppress them at your risk.  The best solution here is to generify the raw type and make it into a generic type.  Absent that, there's no benefit to wrapping a raw type simply to suppress the compiler warnings that you shouldn't be suppressing anyway.  If you can prove that your code really is safe, then you use `@SuppressWarnings`.